# MySQL taking too much time for query, Is NoSQL the solution or something like elasticsearch would work?

Tags: mysql, performance, mongodb, optimization, elasticsearch

I have a mysql table with millions of rows. Each row has an id, data, date.

1. id -> num
2. data -> longtext
3. date -> datetime

column 'data' contains json encoded data, each row in data column is approx. 45kb, if I need to query 100 rows, it returns 45kb x 100 = 4500kb data. The requirement is to fetch 10,000 or 100,000 rows in future.

The json encoded data, is then further decoded at server side(PHP) and then application uses the data.

The application server and database server are both separate. It is taking too much time in querying 100 rows (query is done w.r.t date) at the moment, while querying and transferring data to application server for rendering.

Please suggest optimize solutions for extremely fast access (for 100,000 rows).

Is NoSQL (mongodb) a good solutions, or elasticsearch a good to go, or MySQL has any optimization technique for this scenario ?

Comment: Have you tried Postgres? It has native JSON columns which might mean you don't have to ship the entire JSON data structure over, but instead just the relevant parts.

Comment: use `MYISSAM` as you storage engine in mysql

Comment: What is the actual query you're running on the table?

Comment: Haven't tried postgres yet. The requirement states, that sometimes entire JSON data is required, and sometimes the relevant parts. The ultimate goal is to get the entire data column 45 kb row (n rows) but v.fast.

Comment: the query is
'SELECT * from table WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2014-3-3' AND '2014-3-4'

every 5 min, a new row is entered via CRON.

Comment: @Tabby currently InnoDB is being used, how much will MyISAM optimize it ?

Comment: @TariqMehmood alot , you must be having a backup of the database just try it on the backup file and compare.

Comment: @Tabby I'll try that and do comparison. What I've done right now is, compressed json encoded string via PHP, which has reduced size from 45kb to 4kb and stored it in a blob, but the time to uncompress(blob data) at application end, is consuming the time in contrary.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work for MongoDB developing the PHP Driver.

In MongoDB the "data" field would become just another normal subdocument. Nothing special about it.. It is just an array of information. Just the way we like it :)
You can query on it in any way you want. You can fetch any parts of it you want. You can index it however you like.

This is what document oriented databases like MongoDB do exceptionally well - because they were designed from the get-go with this sort of data in mind

You didn't say what exactly this JSON encoded data is, or looks like, so I can't speak to the precise details... I recommend you just try it out for your self. Build a Proof Of Concept using the various systems and pick the one that makes you most productive and is fast for your usecase.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.insert.php (and the rest of the tutorial) for examples on how this works.

Now, we don't actually store the data in JSON format (we use BSON, Binary JSON), so you don't have to encode the data into JSON. Just use normal PHP arrays and objects - its gonna be faster that way anyway.

Comment: I have tried it. Stored entire array(PHP) into mongo as a document. In this way i have 1000 documents, and similarly 1000 rows in MySQL (as stateed above).
MongoDB is taking too much time with storing array(data column, not json encoded) as document, in comparison to MySQL.
On the other side, if I store JSON encoded string in Mongo inside a document, it is little faster, but it is json string, so unprocessable, if data subparts are required.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a full document, along with the indexes for that collection? Sorting on 1000 documents should feel instant.

Comment: It would be too huge to show up entire document over here.

What effect does take after applying 'indexes' on mongo document ?

Comment: For optimal performance, in any database, you have to "pick correct" index strategy. Things you query on, and sort on, need to be indexed. If they are not indexed then the work the database needs to do is extraordinary and you can just as well hire a trained monkey to look through the data manually and call you when he found it. With an index on the field you are querying/sorting on however this work becomes trivial and "super fast"

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason why you can't do it with MySQL.
The most important thing for fast data access in such a big table is to build good indexes for your queries.

If you want to get the data for a specific date, make sure you have an index like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtable` ADD INDEX `yourindex` ( `date` , `data` )
```

That's the way the MySQL Optimizer processes your queries:
1. Filtering (WHERE clause)
2. Grouping (GROUP BY clause)
3. Ordering (ORDER BY clause)
4. Selecting Data (SELECT * clause)

You should create indexes exactly in this order to completely satisfy your queries by only using the index without a table scan.

If the needed data is already part of the first three index parts, you don't have to add additional columns to the index.

For smaller tables and if you don't need high performance, a index only on the filter column may be enough.

Comment: He should not index data as it is 45kb in size, this means it is a text or blob, and that the index would be massive if possible.  That said having the index on the where clause date field is imperative.  This use case may be a poor fit for MySQL though as BLOB and TEXT type fields have performance penalties.  Not sure why you would use MySQL to store non-relational data, Elastic or Mongo is almost certainly a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot suggest solution within MySQL – do not have much experience with that, but millions of rows from what I know should be no problem in MySQL (never was a problem in SQL Server).  As far as MongoDB is concerned unless you get into area of billions or rows with prospects of going even higher do not even think about MongoDB or any other NoSql solution.

I am developing a website now that has MongoDB as a back-end. We have a problem of slow searches in MongoDB and the size of that collection we are querying is only 400K documents. We envision it to be in the future more like 50M documents, so it a big problem. And while search is complex (it used multiple fields including fields in nested documents there is no reason for it to be that slow in 400K documents). So, one of the solution we contemplating is actually using some SQL database (perhaps even MySQL) for that particular collection/table and that particular search. To speed search up we already gone away with sharing of that collection, that added some speed for searches but not that much.

Bottom line is: be careful with MongoDB – it is not a panacea!

Comment: I'd be interesting in debugging your performance problems with you if you want. Could you post example of a example document, your search criteria, and the indexes in the collection?

Comment: Did you try Elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few way of doing this

1) Use MYISSAM
2) Try Normalizing the json data
3) Use Index
4) Cache, Use Memcache

The last solution i can think of is to use a separate database server, which will have all stored procedures , functions to get the data you want and make sure you only make a single request to this server.

Like you said the compression and decompression takes time, there is no point in doing it then. Try to find other things you can optimize, such as javascripts , HTML load time, then let ajax do the data transfer for you. Work you way around the problem optimize all the easy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

An old question but let be the answer. As mentioned [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103370/are-text-fields-stored-separately-from-the-row-in-mysql-isam) if the record size is more than 7kb then rest of data is stored separately. It takes several ms to fetch millions records by index but takes seconds to read and deliver. So, it seems that long time execution mostly ruled by amount of data needed to be physically read and transfer (45kb*100.000 ~ 5Gb).